# Pandas.Drop all columns with missing values except 1 column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a dataframe with following columns `'Age', 'Name', 'Sex'`, where `'Age'` and `'Sex'` contain missing values. I want to drop all columns with missing values except one column `'Age'`. So that I have a df with 2 columns 'Name' and 'Age'. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Age'  : [5,np.nan,12,43], 
  'Name' : ['Alice','Bob','Charly','Dan'],
  'Sex'  : ['F','M','M',np.nan]})

df_filt = df.loc[:,(-df.isnull().any()) | (df.columns.isin(['Age']))]
```

Explanation:

`df.isnull().any())` checks for all columns if any value is `None` or `NaN`, the `-` means that only those columns are selected that do *not* meet that criterion.

`df.columns.isin(['Age'])` checks for all columns if their name is 'Age', so that this column is selected in any case.

Both conditions are connected by an OR (`|`) so that if either condition applies the column is selected.